# Must I select "The cost basis is incorrect or missing on my 1099‑B" in TurboTax in the case of vested RSUs?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, cost-basis, turbotax, rsu

I file my US taxes via TurboTax as a US lawful permanent resident. Some of my RSUs vested in 2021, which I partly sold in 2021. My employer uses [E-Trade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-Trade) for RSUs.  E-Trade reports on [Form 1099-B](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/f/form-1099-b.asp) that the cost basis for vested RSUs is 0 USD, which is untrue. I can go to https://us.etrade.com/etx/pxy/tax-center and click on `Stock Plan Transactions Supplement` to [view the Adjusted Cost Basis](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/149724/5656).

In TurboTax, after reporting in `Box 1e - Cost basis` the Adjusted Cost Basis, must I check `The cost basis is incorrect or missing on my 1099‑B`?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, because it is incorrect or missing on your 1099-B. This makes it easier for the IRS matching program to identify mistakes. Your return will not match the 1099-B they've received, so by checking this box you're essentially telling them that this is expected (and not that you mistyped something on your return).