# Which version of turbo tax has "The cost basis is incorrect or missing on my 1099‑B" in TurboTax in the case of vested RSUs?

Tags: united-states, taxes, stocks, turbotax, rsu

The RSU cost basis is incorrect on my 1099-B' and it repost 0.  Before the stock was available to me and company sold some of my shares as tax deduction.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Are you asking in what version of TT you can do adjustments to basis on schedule D?

Answer (score -1):

> The RSU cost basis is incorrect on my 1099-B' and it repost 0.

That's not because of TurboTax, but instead  it's due to the way brokers report cost basis for RSUs:
[Why is the cost basis reported by a broker on RSUs 0 USD?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/106319/5656)

See https://money.stackexchange.com/a/149724/5656 on how to report RSU cost basis properly.

Comment: I found the cost basis from eTrade, followed by someone posted in the following steps.  My problem is that I do not how to use TurboxTax to adjust, because it use 0 as cost basis
I tried option:  I have RSU,  and tried option my 1099-B has infor I know is not right ...

1. Go to https://us.etrade.com/etx/pxy/tax-center
2. Click on Stock Plan Transactions Supplement
3. Look at the Adjusted Cost Basis column